# Custom message not working for C++ Project template with Wizard

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, project-template

I have followed the tutorial here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185301.aspx to produce a template project that lets me substitute parameters in my code using a wizard.

This works for all my C# projects for example if I have the following in my template:

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using $customvariable$Definitions;

namespace $customvariable$Objects
{
    /// <summary>
    /// $customvariable$ Camera
    /// </summary>
    public class $customvariable$Camera
    {
        #region Constructor
        /// <summary>
        /// Instantiates a new instance of the $customvariable$Camera class
        /// </summary>
        public $customvariable$Camera() :
            base()
        {

        }
        #endregion
    }
```

I can rename my customvariable to anything I want and it gets generated in the resulting project.

BUT
If I do the exact same in a visual C++ project the custom variables do not get replaced.

How can I get this to work for C++ code files as well

Answer (score 1):

C++ uses a different methodology for replacing template values.  Unfortunately, the syntax is not the same as C#.  One possible solution (although maybe not the best) is to have two separate template files and use a "language" flag to determine which one to use.  Have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730846(vs.80).aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf952e4s(v=vs.110).aspx) for the differences.

Here's an example of how it looks in C++...

```
static AFX_EXTENSION_MODULE [!output PROJ_SOURCE]DLL = { NULL, NULL };

#ifdef _MANAGED
#pragma managed(push, off)
#endif

extern "C" int APIENTRY DllMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, DWORD dwReason, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    // Remove this if you use lpReserved
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpReserved);

    if (dwReason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH)
    {
        TRACE0("[!output PROJ_SOURCE].DLL Initializing!\n");

        // Extension DLL one-time initialization
        if (!AfxInitExtensionModule([!output PROJ_SOURCE]DLL, hInstance))
            return 0;

        // Saves the DLL instance handle for later use with ChangeResCl. 
        resHandle = hInstance;
```

In the code above, the name of the dll is replaced in two separate locations using "[!output PROJ_SOURCE]".

Comment: Thanks, I can get the c++ file names to change when I use the method described above but the parameters in the C++ files dont.  I looked at the two links but I cannot see any examples where a C++ file has parameters substituted.